# How to link to current page url and title with just php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to modify this code for non-javascript share buttons so it will share the current page url and title (which unfortunately the code-writer didn't include how to do http://sharingbuttons.io/ )

```
<!-- Sharingbutton Facebook -->
<a class="resp-sharing-button__link" href="https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" target="_blank" aria-label="">
  <div class="resp-sharing-button resp-sharing-button--facebook resp-sharing-button--small"><div aria-hidden="true" class="resp-sharing-button__icon resp-sharing-button__icon--solid">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M18.77 7.46H14.5v-1.9c0-.9.6-1.1 1-1.1h3V.5h-4.33C10.24.5 9.5 3.44 9.5 5.32v2.15h-3v4h3v12h5v-12h3.85l.42-4z"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

There are several of these buttons, obviously, but I'll use Facebook as the example. I've tried using all the options suggested on the other how-to-get-current-page-url posts on Stack and elsewhere, but they either break the button code or cause clicking the button to open a window that closes before it loads anything.

Answer (score 0):

user facebook opengraph og meta tag to post your site content is ahre dialog

check below link for more details

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters